# C++ FatFs undefined reference to functions

Tags: c++, c, atmelstudio

I have a code written in Atmel Studio to read/write data from a SD card. I am using FatFs here. My problem is the code doesn't compile when I use some of the functions (f_chdir, f_getcwd...) in FatFs. Some functions works fine (f_puts, f_open, f_mount, f_mkdir...). All these functions are located in same header file (ff.h, ff.c)

The error says "undefined reference to -function-, ld returned 1 exit status". When I go to the error it shows the end of the code while it is suppose to show where the error is.

I cannot understand the problem with my code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using version FatFs R0.11 solved the problem. I don't know exactly what happened. This was 4 years back when I started working with `C++` so I must have missed some `#define` in some header file.

Answer (score 4):

Just ran into this using the SD card for a project using SAM4S Xplained Pro (Atmel 7, ASF 3.20).

Make sure you have all the asf projects (fatfs, sd_mmc, memory access control, and then the other basics e.g. pmc, gpio, and maybe a few more).  My asf did NOT include sd_mmc_mem.c and sd_mmc_mem.h for some reason, so I had to include those myself.  Also remember to do the sd_mmc_init() at the top of your main loop.  As for the configuration...

If you look closely at ffconf.h, the first thing it does is include conf_fatfs.h, which (wait for it!) is EXACTLY the same file line by line as ffconf.h.  All the variables are defined there first and foremost (and guarded by an #ifndef FFCONF and NOT an CONF_FATFS) aka that's where it counts..

Go into conf_fatfs.h and change _USE_STRFUNC to 1 or 2 et voila.

Also note that in the places where you use it, you'll have to #include the ff.h preceded by either ffconf.h or conf_access.h

ASF is a real snake pit if you don't know what you're looking for.

Enjoy.

Comment: +1 for recognizing that ASF can be a snake pit if you don't know what you are looking for. Sometimes it's a needle is a haystack. It's a great library but IMO poorly documented.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the memory control access interface is disabled in the ASF wizard. In order to enable the memory control access, please follow the steps below.

1. Open the ASF wizard (Alt + W).
2. Enable the Memory Control Access as follows.

ASF SD sd_mmc_mem.h memory access enable

3. Finally, click the “Apply” option to make the changes.

This adds **sd_mmc_mem.h** /.c files

Answer (score 0):

Open the `ffconf.h` in your favorite editor and set `_FS_RPATH` to `2`. From `ffconf.h`:

```
#define _FS_RPATH       0
/* This option configures relative path feature.
/
/   0: Disable relative path feature and remove related functions.
/   1: Enable relative path feature. f_chdir() and f_chdrive() are available.
/   2: f_getcwd() function is available in addition to 1.
/
/  Note that directory items read via f_readdir() are affected by this option. */
```

Which features of the fatfs library are included in your build is configurable, so that you don't have to lose valuable ROM space (as well as a few bytes of RAM) for functions you're not using.

For versions of the FatFS library prior to 0.8a, `_FS_RPATH` supports only values `0` and `1`; `f_getcwd` is not available in these versions.

Additionally, in versions prior to 0.8, it is necessary for C++ code to explicitly include its headers as C headers to avoid name mangling:

```
extern "C" {
#include "ff.h"
}
```

From version 0.8 onwards, it does this internally. You can find the new versions [here](http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html) if you're still working with an old one -- the comment you left leads me to believe that this might be the case.

Comment: It didn't work. 
I found out this just now. In a c project, problem is as I asked before. But in c++ even f_puts() doesn't work. (undefined reference to 'f_puts()' , ld returned 1 exit status)

Comment: In the C++ project, put `extern "C" { }` around the `#include`s for the fatfs library or download the latest version (R0.11 has that built in). Does `_FS_RPATH` not enable `f_chdir` in the C project, either? In that case, what version of the FatFS library are you using?

Comment: using version R0.11 solved the problem. Thank you for the help @Wintermute

Answer (score 0):

Check if **_FS_MINIMZE** in **ffconf.h** is **0** to have all functions available.
In my version that I downloaded from elm-chan it was by default set to 3 and lead to the compiler error: undefined reference.

Answer (score 0):

In file **ffconf.h**, set #define **_USE_FIND** to 1.

/* This option switches filtered directory read functions, f_findfirst() and
/  f_findnext(). (0:Disable, 1:Enable 2:Enable with matching altname[] too) */

I needed to use f_findfirst() and f_findnext() functions and i was getting undefined reference errors.
Now this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Drive/directory handling functions are under #if _FS_RPATH >= 1 (or similar preprocessors) .